# designing ecto queries on my schema models to support preloading

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I'm trying to get a pattern for all my ecto models that have child associations.

In my controllers sometimes I want to load just the model, and other times I want to load it with all or some of the associations.

```
def get_account!(id), do: Repo.get!(Account, id)
```

Account has the following assocations:

```
has_many :users
belongs_to :company
```

What would be a good way to modify my get_account! function that gives me the option to preload the associations?

I don't want to have this preload code in my controllers, I like having all my query related stuff in the module itself and not leaking in my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to create `with_<association>` functions in your context module, for example:

```
def get_account!(id), do: Repo.get!(Account, id)

def with_company(%Account{} = account), do: Repo.preload(account, :company)

def with_users(%Account{} = account), do: Repo.preload(account, :users)
```

so you can use them in your controller like this:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  account = 
    Context.get_account!(id)
    |> Context.with_company
    |> Context.with_users
  render(conn, "show.html", account: account)
end
```

and you have a fully loaded account available in the view.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can easily extend it with more specific preloads, like `account |> with_most_active_users(10)`.

Comment: This results in several queries against the database (1 main + number of times `Repo.preload` was called,) because `Repo.get!/2` returns an object, not a query.

Answer (score 0):

I usually borrow the approach from how Rails scopes are done. Ecto query accepts another query as a source. One should call `Repo.get` family functions, actually executing the query against the database, as the last call, when all the preloads and other conditions are appended to the query.

So you might introduce the bare template query like:

```
defp do_get_account_query(id),
  do: from(a in Account, where: a.id == ^id)
```

And use it in all your queries with [`Ecto.Repo.one!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:one!/2):

```
def get_account!(id, preloads \\ []) do
  preloads
  Enum.reduce(do_get_account_query(id), fn clause, query ->
    Repo.preload(query, clause)
  end)
  |> Repo.one!()
end
```

For more sophisticated scopes, one might rely on the generic function and derive the scope from it.